# Compiler error: "not a statement"

Tags: java

This is the code snippet:

```
boolean nodesFiltered = false;

filterSet = newNodeSet;
int filterSize;
int i;

for (; predIter.hasNext(); i < filterSize)
{
  eachPred = (Predicate)predIter.next();

  filterSize = filterSet.size();

  i = 0; continue;

  contextNode = filterSet.get(i);

  if (contextNode != null)
  {
    List list = new ArrayList(1);

    list.add(contextNode);

    predContext.setNodeSet(list);

    predContext.setPosition(i + 1);
    predContext.setSize(filterSize);

    predResult = eachPred.evaluate(predContext);
```

Where it says `i < filterSize)` the compiler says I have an error... It says that it isn't a statement...

Comment: Reduce the program to smallest size where you can reproduce the same error. You will most likely figure it out on your own, but if you can't then ask here again

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, this line is incorrect:

```
for (; predIter.hasNext(); i < filterSize)
```

In Java <del>(and all other C-syntax languages)</del> [`for` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) has the following structure:

```
for(initialization; termination; increment) {
  statements...
}
```

where:

- `initialization` **statement** is called once, when the loop starts
- `termination` boolean **expression** is evaluated before each iteration. If it yields `false`, loop terminates
- `increment` **statement** is called after every iteration.

Effectively every `for` loop can be expressed as `while` loop:

```
initialization;
while(termination) {
  statements;
  increment;
}
```

As you can see in your code snippet *increment* block is a boolean expression (returns `boolean`) while it should be a statement (it should "do" something, like incrementing some variable). This is what the compiler is trying to say.

Comment: it would be helpful i could add the whole code block but i can't...:'(

Comment: I don't know anything about Java, but the OP's original `for` statement is definitely correct in C because of that semicolon.

Comment: Like @Marlon says, [C](http://ideone.com/RIpmnT) and [C++](http://ideone.com/aN3FfJ) have no issues with that, but [Java](http://ideone.com/hZSHXm) and [C#](http://ideone.com/vdi56L) don't like it.

Comment: @Marlon: thanks for clarifying this. Although the syntax and structure of `for` is the same in C and Java but seems like the Java compiler is more strict. I removed the part about C syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The last part of the for loop should be a statement -- it's what will be executed when control hits the bottom of the loop.

Remember, for a for loop `for(int i = 0; i < foo; i++)`, control goes like this:

1. `int i = 0;` (perform initializer statement)
2. `i < foo;` (perform conditional check)
3. if yes, execute the body of the loop.
4. `i++` (perform increment step)
5. Back to 2.

As you can see, 4. needs something to happen, rather than just getting the value of an expression.

Answer (score 0):

What you did wrong was that in a for loop the code sequence is:

```
for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
//Code goes here
}
```

The problem is:

```
//You did *no* initialization, the order was wrong, and no increment. 
for (; predIter.hasNext(); i < filterSize) //wrong
for (i=0; i < filterSize; i++) //Right
```

Hope this helps!